# HighCharts: use an anonymous function in maincontentText

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to improve the content of a popup created in highcharts.

In my use case, the content is becoming a little complex, so I would prefer to use an anonymous function to format it, but the function isn't evaluated, and is displayed as text instead

[image: result and expected output]

You can see directly in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbfppkhq/). If you click on a data point, the popup is displayed

```
maincontentText: function () {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' + this.y + ' visits'
},
```

But the same thing works with the tooltip formatter

```
formatter: function () {
    return "<b>" + this.x + '</b><br>' ;
}
```

replacing maincontentText by this and it works (but for my need it's not flexible enough)

```
maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> '
+ this.y + ' visits',
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there an other way to create a popup with a content generated via script (preferably while keeping highcharts)

Comment: can you please tell how to show your data.

Comment: on the fiddle, click on a point of the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make a function and call it so that if any change needed you change only that function. for that 
Make a function

```
function anoFunc(x,y){
  return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' + this.y + ' visits'
  }
```

And in the plotOptions.series.events.click

use this

```
maincontentText: anoFunc(this.x,this.y)
```

hope it is what you looking for

Comment: wow, thanks for the fast response! I created a fiddle that works with your suggestion! http://jsfiddle.net/7zta5uex/

Comment: great, anytime. :)